# Can we allow the comment section (under All Replies >> Oldest) inside the "Discussion Board" list to show more than 20 replies on each page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, discussion-board, pnp

We have added a Discussion Board list to our sharepoint online classic team site.
[image]

Currently when we click on a discussion item, the main view (under All Replies >> Oldest) 
[image]

for each discussion will show maximum of 20 replies, and then it will show a paging link as follow:-

[image]

but most users miss this paging and think that the discussion only contain 20 replies. so can i expand the replies section to show more than 20? using the UI or using PnP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this limitation number with SharePoint Designer 2013:

1. Open the Discussion Board list and then open SharePoint Designer via LIST > Edit List.
2. Navigate to SharePoint Designer 2013 > Lists and Libraries > Discussion Board list > Views > Flat and open Flat.aspx.
3. Search for `<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">20</RowLimit>`. “20” is the number of replies that can be displayed on one page. Change this number and then save.

Please note that too many replies on a single page may lead to performance issue.

[image]